# $v \in \hom(\hom(V,W),W) $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to show that if $ v \in V$ then $ v \in \hom(\hom(V,W),W))$ where $\hom(V,W)$ denotes the space of linear transformations form $V$ to $W$.

I see that $\hom(V,W)$ is a vector space, so that the double hom makes sense. Also, in some sense I intuitively understand why this would be true. How does it follow that $ v \in \hom(\hom(V,W),W))$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$

To show that $v \in \Hom(\Hom(V,W),W)$, you need to define how $v$ acts on a member of $\Hom(V,W)$.  So:  Take any $\phi \in \Hom(V,W)$.  How can you define $v(\phi)$?  Keep in mind that it needs to be a member of $W$.  There is only one natural way to do it (Hint:  it makes use of the fact that $\phi$ is already a map from $V \to W$.)

Note:  I actually think it is poor form to say that $v \in \Hom(\Hom(V,W),W)$.  The element we have just defined is not actually the same object as the vector $v \in V$; rather, it is a natural "copy" of it.  A more precise way to describe this situation would be to say that for every $v \in V$ there exists a $\hat{v} \in \Hom(\Hom(V,W),W)$, so that $V$ is isomorphic to a subspace $\hat{V} \subset \Hom(\Hom(V,W),W)$.

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck until I saw this. So the natural way to define $v(\phi)$ would just be the evaluation map from $\phi \to W$, right? And then v is certainly an element of the image of the evaluation map by the definition? Does this show everything we need?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, which makes me suspect you are not understanding my answer.  Remember, $v(\phi)$ is not supposed to be a *map*, it is supposed to be *an element of $W$*.  There is only one obvious element available.

Comment: You're right. That didn't make sense on second thought. But now I am a bit confused. $v$ is a vector in the space $V$. So how do we say that a vector acts on a transformation? Are you saying to define $v(\phi)=\phi(v)$, since $\phi(v)=w$ for some $w \in W$? If that is indeed the idea, I am not quite sure intuitively how that works.

Comment: You've got it, and you are right to be confused, because the vector $v$ does *not* act on transformations; rather, for each $v$,there is a naturally-defined "transformation of transformations" $\hat{v}$ that acts on transformations via $\hat{v}(\phi)=\phi(v)$.  But because the mapping $v \mapsto \hat{v}$ embeds $V$ as a subspace of $\Hom(\Hom(V,W),W)$ it is commonplace (although a bit sloppy) to simply identify $v$ and $\hat{v}$.  (That was the point of my second paragraph.)